# How to get time in HHMM format few minutes hence the time now?

Tags: date, time

I have to create a file with the name `X.<current_date_and_time>_<time in HHMM>` where the time is 3 minutes hence the time now

for example: If the current date is 9/17/2016 and current time is 14.21 filename should be: `X.20160917.1421_1424`

command I am using for this is:

```
mv sample.xml A$(date +%Y%m%d.%H%M)_$((date +%H%M)+ 3m)
```

It's not working because of including + 3m.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming GNU `date(1)`:

```
mv sample.xml A"$(date +%Y%m%d.%H%M)_$(date -d 'now +3 minutes' +%H%M)"
```

Comment: This is accurately working. Thanks Sato Katsura!

Answer (score 1):

With [dateutils](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/)

```
dateadd --format '%H%M' --zone 'Your/Time Zone' now +3m
```